# How do I get my ejs form to autofill the ID value for the person filling out the form?

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

Essentially, the user is creating an event, and I want the user's id to be autofilled as the organizer value.
Currently, the event is created by the user filling out a form with all the necessary details (title, location, etc.). But I want it to autofill ID and submit that with the rest of the data

I was trying something like this, but it's throwing errors and telling me that the id value is undefined, even though my code has no problems grabbing that value when using it to show that person's name on the home screen

Here's the part of the form as it currently stands:

`<label for="inputOrganizer">Organizer ID:</label> <br/> <input type="mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId" name="organizer" id="inputOrganizer" placeholder="Organizer" value="<%= currentUser._id %>" required />`

(On the home screen, to show the person's name by searching for them via ID, I have this code:

`<% if (loggedIn) { %> Logged in as <a href="<%=`/users/${currentUser._id}`%>"><%= currentUser.name %></a>` 
(note that there's a ` before and after the /users string but it won't show it because that's used to put it in a text box thingy)

and that works fine. Replacing "._id" with ".name" didn't fix the error, nor did putting it in the ${} thing.)